# Enlarge a Qt widget so it might cover other widgets

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a complex layout of widgets in widgets in widgets in a QMainWindow. In one of them I have an image, it sits in the corner. What I would like to achieve is following: if the image is activated (e.g. clicked upon), it should be enlarged, so it might overlap other widgets, or parts of other widgets. The problem is, I still would like it to remain in the layout, but in a way that everything else remains in its original size and position.

I was thinking about having an empty but similar size widget as a "placeholder", and have the actual resizable widget float on top of it. My problem is, that it does not guarantee that it stays in its position if the main window is resized, maximized, etc. Is there a better or more efficient way to do it?

Comment: How about this: when the user clicks on the image, a dialog (containing only the image) appears over the image, enlarges (by applying an animation of some sort). it's the reverse of your placeholder idea: make the actual widget stay where it is, and another widget, a QDialog, do the floating.

Comment: @Erich Lancaster: I'll give it a try. A problem would arise if the window is moved, but I intend to use my application maximized (there is still an issue with different screen sizes, but I can just position the QDialog approprietly)

Comment: Hmmm, yes that would mean the Floating Dialog would have to listen to move events from the parent, which leads me to think that there has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Even if it listens to the move events and tries to replicate them, its movements will not be that smooth as if it was part of the same window.

Comment: I was thinking precisely the same thing...sorry, I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can't find a better solution, I think I'll do the following:

The MainWindow will have no layout, just two QWidgets on top of each other. The bottom one will contain all the layouts and everything else, while the upper one will have a transparent background and the resizable widget, maybe supported with a number of spacers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, if the widgets to be overlapped are in the same layout than the one you want to enlarge, and the policies for that widget allow it, is just `.setVisible(false)` in the other widgets. The widget that remains visible should resize to cover all the available area!

Comment: The problem is that it's not flexible enough. I'll not be able to cover only parts of other widgets.

Comment: Oh, wait, I thought you wanted to cover everything.